# Find and replace text in files within Directories and Sub-directories from CSV file

Tags: powershell, replace, find

I thought what I was looking for was simple and had been done before but after several hours of searching I’m not so sure!

I need to conduct a Find & Replace of text within a directory of files to include subdirectories, based upon values from a CSV file.

The CSV file has two simple columns: FindText | ReplaceText

[This Powershell script](http://tangodude.wordpress.com/2013/04/15/powershell-multiple-find-replace-in-files-with-lookup-list/) comes close, but it doesn’t search sub-directories. Can anyone please extend this Powershell script to make it also search all subdirectories within the target directory?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get all files in sub directories please use -Recurse where $path is a path to parent directory. 
It gets all txt files including sub folders.

```
Get-ChildItem $path -Recurse -include *.txt
```

Comment: That works great, thank you. Just a quick unrelated follow-up question. Set-Content adds a carriage return to the end of files, even though there was no find string within these files. This is making things a little difficult for me as I am running this script against a large VS project in TFS. Is there any way to tell Set-Content to supress adding a carriage return, and thus modifying a file which it really has no business modifying?!